# Change DLL's while application is running

Tags: qt, curl, dll, openssl, runtime

I have an application that uses `libcurl-4.dll` and `libcurl.dll.a` files.

I have two sets of libcurl DLL's, one built with `OpenSSL` for using explicit CA certificates, and one built with `WinSSL` for using Windows system store.

By default, the application uses the DLL's with `WinSSL` supprt to begin execution. The application at start time, parses an XML file, and this is where the user would be specifying the file name or path to certificates they would like to use. If these paths/files in the XML are valid, then I want to swap to the DLL's that were built with `OpenSSL`, before any of my `curl_easy_setopt` function calls are made.

Is this something that would be possible?

Comment: You'd need to link Qt with the SSL dll's set to on-demand loading, and then explicitly open the library you desire. Once you do, the relevant functions will resolve, and the default demand-load library won't be accessed (I hope).

Comment: My other experiment I have yet to try is, since the DLL's are the same name, just name them separately such as winssl-libcurl-4.dll and openssl-libcurl-4.dll and load them both into memory at run time and see I can force support from both that way.

Comment: These dlls presumably both export the same symbols - if so, then loading them at the same time won't work. Even if they had different symbol names - how would you select between the two?

Comment: For Windows hot-patching, see the [Detours Library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) fro Microsoft Research. I've used it before and its very cool. But usually you just want to use `LoadLibrary` and friends to bring in the right library; or you swap in the correct certificate store at runtime.